Azure: Check if a member is part of a group & export to excel
I am trying to write a script that checks a list of members if they are part of different groups in azure, then export the list to excel. I am not sure if there is a native way of doing this in Azure as I am new to Azure, so I have been trying to tackle this via PowerShell. Im just struggling.
An Example of what the output to look like:



DisplayName
Group 1
Group 2
Group 3




User 1
Yes
Yes
Yes


User 2
Yes
No
Yes


User 3
No
Yes
No


User 4
Yes
Yes
Yes




You can do this in PowerShell, sure.
You can also do it using VBA directly in Excel, but there's a lot more work required. PowerShell is suitable because it has all the cmdlets you'll need to interact with Azure / Entra.
You'll need the Az PowerShell module so make sure this is installed.
The example below will:

Define a list of users
Define a list of groups
Connect to Azure
For each group, retrieve the group members
For each user, check if they are a member of the group
Build a two-dimensional hashtable matching the desired structure
Output the data in table format
Outout a CSV which will work with Excel

# Import Az module and connect to Azure
Import-Module Az
Connect-AzAccount

# Define lists of users and groups
$users = "User1", "User2", "User3"
$groups = "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"

# Create empty hashtable to store data
$data = @{}

# Build hashtable with default values (false)
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $data[$user] = @{}
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $data[$user][$group] = $false
    }
}

# Iterate each group and retrieve the members using the group name. Check if each user is present, for each group, and update the hashtable
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $groupMembers = Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupDisplayName $group
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        if ($groupMembers.DisplayName -contains $user) {
            $data[$user][$group] = $true
        }
    }
}

# Convert hashtable to custom objects to get table header name in output
$objects = foreach ($user in $users) {
    [PSCustomObject]$data[$user] | Select-Object @{Name="DisplayName"; Expression={$user}}, *
}

# Format the table
$objects | Format-Table -Property DisplayName, Group1, Group2, Group3

# We can also export this output to CSV file
$objects | Export-Csv C:\path\to\file.csv


You should be able to adapt this script per your requirements.
